# Tensorflow retrain wrong

Tags: image, tensorflow, classification, detect

I'm new to tensorflow and trying to classify a game objects / monsters / characters , so I tried to classify this kind of robot (attached pictures) and created like 30 pictures
I trained it to 0.9% loss ( about 300 steps) but for some reason It classifies it wrong .

also I followed this tutorial (sentdex) pythonprogramming.net/testing-custom-object-detector-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/?completed=/training-custom-objects-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/

Someone can help me recognize the problem ?

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgoSf.jpg)

Comment: Can you clarify a few things:
- What model/code are you using? 
- What do you mean by "It classifies it wrong"?
- What are the different images showing?

Comment: Also, it may be more helpful to ask the [community on pythonprogramming.net](https://pythonprogramming.net/community/), since the users there are probably more familiar with the tutorial you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have at least 100+ images for training, 30 is too less. For decent results try with at least 200 images is what i would suggest to start with and then ensure you are following all steps you mentioned in the article without any mistakes. This has worked for many people including me, so should for you as well.

Refer the other links in my SO post if you need more articles -

[Reduce number of objects a pretrained Tensorflow model detects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50866894/reduce-number-of-objects-a-pretrained-tensorflow-model-detects/50899895#50899895)