# Reduce number of objects a pretrained Tensorflow model detects

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I am using [this code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb) for object detection and it outputs 100 boxes even though in most pictures there are 0-5 objects. The detection takes 5 seconds on a 250X250 image. Would cutting the number of objects to be detected speed up the process, and if yes is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Logically it would, i cant say exactly by how much. You can retrain the model to only fewer objects that you are interested in. For training you will also specify objects interested in a file with extension *.pbtxt which has list of objects specified.

Few Links which talk about retraining in detail
https://pythonprogramming.net/training-custom-objects-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/

https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-toy-detector-with-tensorflow-object-detection-api-63c0fdf2ac95

https://medium.com/@dana.yu/training-a-custom-object-detection-model-41093ddc5797

Comment: Just the inference takes less than a second, check your code if you are creating a new session with every inference?